# Is there a way to analyze stacked data as an ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

My data is set up like this:

```
Animal  Treatment  Item  Measurement
1        con       HG    10
2        trt1      HG    20
3        trt2      HG    30
1        con       BCS   2
2        trt1      BCS   3
3        trt2      BCS   3
```

But I have a lot more than that in my actual data set. I have 45 animals and we had 80 different "items" investigated so the list on animals repeats over and over. Each item is listed and the corresponding measurement is in the last column.

When I try to create a model and run an anova it says my df is way too high because it is comparing the whole data set instead of splitting up by item

My code is as follows:

```r
model1 <- lm(Measurement ~ Item+Treatment, data = animal)

Anova(model1, type=3)

emmeansanimal <- emmeans(model1, pairwise~Treatment|Item)
emmeansanimal
```

An example of the output is:

```
Item = BCS:
 Treatment   emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 CON          5.176 12.8 881   -20.03     30.4
 OVER         3.563 12.8 881   -21.62     28.7
 RES          1.202 12.5 881   -23.36     25.8
```

how do I make sure it only includes each group of animals for each item in the df and not the entire dataset?
The summary stats look perfect so I am out of ideas.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here.  Do you want *separate* model fits for each item?  (How are the 45 animals distributed across items? How many observations total?)  This might end up being a better [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question (i.e. *what* you should do more than *how* you should do it ...)

Comment: Equally across items, all 45 animals had HG, BCS, and other measurements collected. So 45 observations per item and there are 80 or so items. I was hoping that these could be analyzed from the same data set if they were in stacked column formats so that I wouldn't have to code for each item and could just do a simple pairwise comparison looking at differences in measurements as a result of treatment effect

Comment: You might be looking for `lmList()` (slightly different versions available in `nlme` and `lme4` packages)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I tried that and it as follows:

model2 <- lmList(Measurement ~ Item|Treatment, data = F1RamNecropsy)
summary(model2)

That looks more right, but the standard error and degrees of freedom is huge

     Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
CON  2.904167   32.13362 0.09037782 0.9280086
OVER 2.720833   32.13362 0.08467248 0.9325420
RES  2.836111   26.23699 0.10809589 0.9139455

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to do. I thought you would want `lmList(Measurement ~ Treatment|Item)` ... ???

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to explain it better, when I ran it that way with treatment first the values for the "Estimate" that the output gives you were way off, because that should be the average right? So when I did Item|Treatment the estimates looked more correct but the SE is way off it is the same SE for every single Item

Comment: can you construct a [mcve] ?